# Edit Pivot Page template in WP7

Tags: templates, windows-phone-7, styles, windows-phone-7.1

I want to change some size of fonts in pivot template. For example I want to set to Pivot Title to be little bigger then it is default, is it posible? And is posible to add search image to right border in line with title of pivot? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change almost everything about the pivot including the size of fonts.
Something like this:

```
    <controls:Pivot>
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="150" Text="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

You may also need to change other elements of the template to adjust for the change in header size.

Don't put a search button in the pivot item header, you should put it in the appbar instead. If the search only applies to one item then you should update the appbar as the selected pivot item is changed.